# How do I get the location of a user?

Tags: javascript, api, geolocation, google-api

I am able to get the user's IP address in my website.  Now i need his country, city, region using his IP i got..  I am trying Google's Geolocation API with the following code,

```
    <div id="yourinfo"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQIAAAAp04yNttlQq-7b4aZI_jL5hQYPm-xtd00hTQOC0OXpAMO40FHAxQMnH50uBbWoKVHwgpklyirDEregg"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if(google.loader.ClientLocation)
        {
            visitor_lat = google.loader.ClientLocation.latitude;
            visitor_lon = google.loader.ClientLocation.longitude;
            visitor_city = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.city;
            visitor_region = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.region;
            visitor_country = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.country;
            visitor_countrycode = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.country_code;
            document.getElementById('yourinfo').innerHTML = '<p>Lat/Lon: ' + visitor_lat + ' / ' + visitor_lon + '</p><p>Location: ' + visitor_city + ', ' + visitor_region + ', ' + visitor_country + ' (' + visitor_countrycode + ')</p>';
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById('yourinfo').innerHTML = '<p>Whoops!</p>';
        }
    </script>
```

Really this code is not working for me.  It is executing the else part and displays Whoops!.
How to get the Geolocation of users.  Any other idea let me know.

I already tried the following code which works well, but takes 6 Seconds of delay in free version.  Later i came to know that google is giving this sevice for free..  So i am try on that.

```
http://services.ipaddresslabs.com/iplocation/locateip?key=SAK58RWP983694534K4Z&ip=".$ClientIP
```

Thank you in Advance

Comment: One of my fried told me that this google api for geolocation will work only in US.  Is it true?

Comment: Is there any other way to geocode IP with google api where i should get xml response.???

Comment: I just tried to use the API link you import from google.com and it works well in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nErrt/). Maybe you have issues retrieving the script (try accessing the API's URL directly to see if it properly returns the JS). Also, according to how Google's script is written, if you already defined `window.google` then the script wouldn't load (see the `if` structure at the beginning of the script). Also, the geoloc works outside the US, as I'm in Europe and got a pretty accurate geoloc. Hope this could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are happy to go with HTML5 you should visit this [tutorial on geolocation](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/html5/geo-location.html).

Answer (score 0):

use this on client side:

http://services.ipaddresslabs.com/iplocation/locateip?key=SAK58RWP983694534K4Z&ip=local-ip

its working fine with me.

By the way, the above key is blocked, you have to get new key instead.